# Django Dynamic Scraper: Automatically Scrape a HUGE amount of urls at scale #143

Tags: django-dynamic-scraper

I am currently working on a project whose goal is to create scrapers in a dynamic way and then being able to process a huge amount of urls at scale.

For example, I have in DDS two websites: [www.xxx.it](http://www.xxx.it) associated with Scraper IT and [www.xxx.ca](http://www.xxx.ca) associated with Scraper CA.

I want to send an infinite amount of urls to DDS, and I want all the urls in the form xxx.it/* to be scraped by Scraper IT, and all the urls in the form xxx.ca/* to be scraped by Scraper CA. I want this to be automatically inferred and done by DDS.

Is there a way to achieve this with the current implementation?